# Controlar mensajes en formularios laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo un formulario el cual me arroja una consulta de una determinada cantidad de registros, quiciera que cuando aparezcan estos registros muestre un mensaje en la parte de arriba que diga cuantos registros consulto, pero no tengo idea de como manejar estos mensajes en laravel, alguien sabe alguna tecnica?

he tratado de hacerlo asi..

```html
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function listusuario()
    {

        $user=user::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
        $conteo=User::count();
        return view('usuario.ecuenta',compact('user'));
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('IT WORKS!');

    }
```

y pretendo recibirlo asi en la vista

```html
 @if(session('success'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <h1>{{session('success')}}</h1>
      </div>
      @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo mandaría ambas variables a la vista, de este modo:

```
public function listusuario()
    {

        $user=user::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
        $conteo=User::count();
        return view('usuario.ecuenta')->with(["user" => $user, "conteo" => $conteo]);
        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('IT WORKS!');

    }
```

Con ayuda del método `with()` logras enviar mas de una variable a tu vista, solo las acomode en forma de arreglo asociativo; es decir en el formato de `"clave" => $valor`

Posterior a eso, en tu vista solo debería ser así:

```
Total de registros: {{ $conteo }}
```

Comment: Excelente amigos, yo pense que era mas complejo, pero en realidad funcion, hasta sale en un recuadro verde, muchas gracias